# Assigning /Storing Highlighted text as a variable in Tkinter Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, variable-assignment, highlight

I am writing a program in Python on Ubuntu, to import files from a folder then single Left click for Highlight the filename

I am trying to Store or Assign the highlighted text as as a variable?

Is there a python function that will allow me to capture the text that is currently highlighted with the single left click and store it as a variable?

Can you please guide me on how do I achieve this task?

```
import subprocess,os
from Tkinter import *


def text_click_callback(event):
    # an event to highlight a line when single click is done
    line_no = event.widget.index("@%s,%s linestart" % (event.x, event.y))
    #print(line_no)
    line_end = event.widget.index("%s lineend" % line_no)
    event.widget.tag_remove("highlight", 1.0, "end")
    event.widget.tag_add("highlight", line_no, line_end)
    event.widget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")




def viewFile():
    tex.delete('1.0', END)

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        linkname="link-" + f
        tex.insert(END,f + "\n", linkname)
        tex.tag_configure(linkname, foreground="blue", underline=True)
        tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<Button-1>", text_click_callback )    # highlight a line



if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=1, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="ViewFile",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 6, column =3)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",            font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 6, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)                                      # TextBox For Displaying File Information
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("/tmp")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you wanting to store the highlight information as well as the text, or only the text?

Comment: just text which Highlighted by single click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text using the same index that you use to highlight it:

```
the_text = event.widget.get(line_no, line_end)
```